# gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 Error

Tags: iphone, c, gcc, build

i downloaded a project and i want to try it, but when i'm trying to compile it i get always this error:

```
Build TuneIn Radio of project TuneInRadio with configuration Release

Ld "build/Release-iphonesimulator/TuneIn Radio.app/TuneIn Radio" normal i386
cd /Users/marco/Downloads/projects
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/build/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/marco/Downloads/projects -L/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/TuneInRadio-iphonesimulator -L/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/MMS/build/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/ffmpeg/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/marco/Downloads/projects -filelist "/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/build/TuneInRadio.build/Release-iphonesimulator/TuneIn Radio.build/Objects-normal/i386/TuneIn Radio.LinkFileList" -lTuneInRadio -llibmms -lffmpegLib -ObjC -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -lz.1 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MapKit -o "/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/build/Release-iphonesimulator/TuneIn Radio.app/TuneIn Radio"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/TuneInRadio-iphonesimulator' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/marco/Downloads/projects/MMS/build/Release-iphonesimulator' following -L not found
ld: library not found for -lTuneInRadio
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any advice on what kind of steps i can follow to reach the error ?

Thank's

Comment: ... Did you try **reading** the error message? It says right there, "directory <whatever>" not found. Usually, this is because the directory in question doesn't actually exist. It can't compile your code if it can't find your files, and it can't find your files if it can't find the folder that you're claiming they're in. Check the path. Do you understand what the commands you're running actually do?

Comment: Try clean all target. It should help.

Comment: -_-' thank's ... in fact inside the project the folder name was Release-iphoneos instead of Release-iphonesimulator. Fixed it, no i have another error but not connected with gcc. Thank's all

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the problem:

ld: library not found for -lTuneInRadio

this means that your build/make is trying to find a library (called libTuneInRadio) to compile this program you're trying to build but it can't find it in the paths (the default ones + the ones described by the '-L' options on gcc call).

Not knowing any more about what you're compiling/building makes it impossible to say precisely what's happening other than you're missing this library.

Given the name of the library, it sounds like it should be part of the project you're trying to build (or maybe there is a related TuneInRadio-lib project), so I would suggest reading the README or BUILDING or similarly named file that might have come with the project to determine how to successfully compile this program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem compiling the project for iOS simulator, the problem is that the source code you downloaded does not contain the libTuneRadio.a library for TuneInRadio-iphonesimulator, so first create that folder and second move the libTuneRadio.a from TuneInRadio-iphoneos to the recently created folder. That should make it.

My application compiled successfully but it crashes as it cannot find any CasseteAudioPlayer class, so i guess there is still something wrong.